# Prevent Duplicate Message in RabbitMQ over Lifetime of Program

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a scraper that runs once a day. It takes about 2 hours to collect all the data. So it wakes up at e.g. 20:00 and shuts down around 22:00.

I have one dispatcher that adds messages to a queue. I have `N` worker that consume the message. A message consists of an `Id` (basically an integer). Once a worker consumed a message and does process it, it gets a result and stores the result in a database. Now it can be that the dispatcher dispatches two messages at different times that contain the same message body i.e. the same `Id`.

E.g. the dispatcher might dispatch a message with `Id=42` at 21:05 and another message with `Id=42` at 21:30. Note that over the 2 hours, it dispatches thousands of message, not only those twos.

So we basically have a duplicate. I'm wondering: What's the best way of handling that? I can't handle it on the side of the dispatcher since it's non-deterministic. I have no way of making sure it only dispatches unique `Id`s without storing them somewhere.

Note that when the duplicate is added to the queue, the original might already be removed because it got handled.

The obvious way to solve this would probably be to check the database for a result that resulted from a specific `Id` but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it. Maybe I could let the exchange store all the `Id`s or something similar?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: A dispatcher which can dispatch duplicates? Can you elaborate on how that can happen (I see it is _"non-deterministic"_ but how so)? That sounds like where a solution should be applied, if at all possible. And how can you guarantee that a database check would be a solution, in that case? That might minimize - but not eliminate - duplicates.

Comment: I query a third-party source for geographical data. The geographical landscape is split into several zones (think of zip codes e.g.) yet those are non-unique identifier (at least where I am from). Now of course there are unique identifiers but I can use them to query my third-party source. So sometimes two different query overlap (in a geographical sense), returning information that I already got from a different, previous query. In short: I rely on a third-party source and can't influence it. There are other solutions I might check, but they are way too involved at the moment.

Comment: A database check would eliminate duplicates because the third-party sources has a unique ID for each result. Of course, you still have kind of a "race condition" on the DB entry because of the concurrency but that's solveable, I guess.

Comment: "_a unique ID for each result_" - I assume you meant to write "_a unique ID for each unique result_". In that case, one possible approach: add a unique constraint to your DB for that ID column. Catch errors from inserts which fail (because they are duplicates) and ignore them. Without that, you cannot _guarantee_ the lookup approach will work, unless you are very careful about your DB transactions (2 simultaneous identical results from 2 different workers - both perform lookups, neither lookup finds any existing ID in the DB, both write to the DB. Unlikely? Maybe yes. Impossible? Maybe no).

Comment: Yeah what you describe is basically the race condition I worry about. Thanks for the quick discussion. I'm also gonna try to use the deduplication plugin for RabbitMQ that let's me cache the IDs on an exchange level.